# Moving all array values for one index

Tags: arraylist

One word: Highscores. And Java.

Top 5 highscores for my game are stored in ArrayList of 5 indexes, I seem to understand everything except moving all elements for one index up. For example: A new player has more points than the previously ranked 1st player, so he replaces him. Now the previously first player is second, the second is third and so on.

Comment: Are you tied to the approach of using an `array`?

Comment: Have you considered using a `PriorityQueue`?

Comment: My java skills aren't that good and I have to do this as an assignment. Arraylist is the type of approach I mostly understand.

Comment: I never used it nor heard of it, so I think it would actually be harder for me to do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly your situation, the following code should do what you are asking for:

```
ArrayList<Integer> highscores = new ArrayList<>();

//...add elements to array 

int newHighscore = 1000;

/* add the new highscore to the first index of the array and automatically
   increment the indices of the elements that are after it */
highscores.add(0, newHighscore); 

//remove the last highscore from the list
highscores.remove(highscores.size() - 1);
```

If you want a more detailed example, I can expand on it.

Comment: so, highscores.add with index will move all next indexes for +1 ? If yes, then I understand and you sir have just solved my problem.

Comment: See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E)

Comment: @user3204315 yes, see beaker's comment above.

Comment: Okay, thanks to everybody who contributed. You guys helped me a lot.